# Graphing with Python plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am conducting an analysis just for fun and I'm running into this problem. I have tried it multiple times before but I can't figure out why it is not working this time.

```
january_city = january_analytic.groupby('city').sum().sort_values(by = 'Quantity Ordered',ascending = False)['Quantity Ordered']
january_city
```

And the result is:
city

San Francisco CA    2661

Los Angeles CA      1716

New York City NY    1513

Boston MA           1174

Dallas TX            878

Atlanta GA           876

Seattle WA           810

Austin TX            582

Portland OR          555

Portland ME          138

And as I am trying to plot the data above:

```
results = [city for city, df in january_analytic.groupby('city')]
plt.bar(results, january_city)
plt.xticks(results, rotation = 'vertical')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('city')
plt.ylabel('Amount Order')
plt.show()
```

It shows that Atlanta has the value of San Francisco which has the highest sale, and it is not right.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,

I should not do `sort_values(by = '....')`

If i just leave it as
`january_city = january_analytic.groupby('city').sum()['Quantity Ordered']`

Then the graph is right